# Sys.sleep with runif, set and use variable

Tags: r, variables

I just want to create a variable I can set to certain values to use it afterwards with runif for Sys.sleep function (for different functions):

```
sys_sleep_var = c(0.2, 0.4)
Sys.sleep(runif(1, sys_sleep_var))
```

This doesn't work, it seems to be easy to fix, but I dont know how. Thanks in advance!

The result should be this:

```
Sys.sleep(runif(1,0.2,0.4))
```

Comment: define two variables: runif_min and runif_max and use them seperately: Sys.sleep(runif(1, runif_min, runif_max))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes wrong in your runif()

You need to provide a min and max, otherwise it is between 0-1

```
runif(n = 1, min = 0.2, max = 0.4)
```

What you basically do is provide a vector as value for min which picks the first value, so you range between 0.2 and 1

```
runif(n = 1, min = c(0.2, 0.4))
```

You can solve it using this:

```
runif(1, sys_sleep_var[1], sys_sleep_var[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a bunch of variables as arguments to a function, put them in a list and use `do.call`:

```r
sys_sleep_var = list(1, 0.2, 0.4)
Sys.sleep(do.call(runif, sys_sleep_var))
```